# PHP Check if dynamic checkboxes aren't checked

Tags: php

I have a form where a list is populated from a MySQL database and checkboxes are assigned for each one using the `$index` method.

When the form is posted, I then cycle through the checkboxes using the following

```
foreach ($_POST['check'] as $index => $value) {
    if (($_POST['check'][$index] == '1')) {
```

How could I check if none of the checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkboxes are not sent if not checked.

So, you can use `if (!isset($_POST['check'])) {}`

Comment: So will that apply if ALL of the checkboxes arn't checked?

Edit - yes it does. Thank you good sir.

Comment: Yes, if the checkboxes arn't checked

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, count number of checked checkboxes:

```
$counter = 0;

foreach ($_POST['check'] as $index => $value) {
    if (($_POST['check'][$index] == '1')) {
        // Do something

        $counter++;
    }
}

if ($counter == 0) {
    // Do something if no checkboxes are selected
}
```

Also you can just check if your `$_POST['check']` is empty:

```
if (empty($_POST['check'])) {
    // Do something if no checkboxes are selected
}
```